# Clipping Image when it goes outside TD border

Tags: html, css

I've looked everywhere I can't think of a solution to this problem. I've also looked on this site but can't find anything.

I have a table and each TD has an image within it. When I hover over the img I want it to move down 100px but not flow outside of the TD (I want it to be cropped when it goes beyond the border of the TD). Right now it just moves down 100px and it's not clipped. Here is my table and CSS:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="_images/ARDLThumbLarge.jpg" alt="ARDL Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td> 
        <td><img src="_images/ThousandYearsThumbLarge.jpg" alt="1000 Years Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td>
        <td><img src="_images/TableThumbLarge.jpg" alt="Table Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

img:hover {
   position:relative;
   top: 103px; 
}
```

I've tried using the clip property, table-layout: fixed, but that just moves all my images into the same location or makes them move on top of each other. Nothing I try works and I can't think of any other places to look.

I just want the images to move down and get cropped when they go beyond the borders of the TD.

Comment: try to add overflow:hidden to the td's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use some better markup to achieve this. The `<table>` element is made for tabular data, and what you are after is a layout.

We can achieve the same affect with the CSS property: `display: table` placed on a parent div and `display: table-cell` placed on the inner divs that contain the images.

- The inner divs are given a fixed height and `overflow: hidden` to cut off the taller images.
- When each inner div is hovered, its image element is pushed down by half of its height with `transform: translateY(50%)`. This reveals the second half of the image.
- The transition provides a smooth animation

#### Example

This works best when the images are all the same height that is exactly twice the height of the inner divs.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper > div:hover img {
  transform: translateY(50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYac.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYac.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYac.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYac.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `overflow:hidden`

```
table td{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xjtba5Lt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try it-

```css
table{
       border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td{
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    display: block;
}
img:hover {
   position:relative;
   top: 103px; 
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v298/Decinoge/bg2_img.png" alt="ARDL Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td> 
        <td><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v298/Decinoge/bg2_img.png" alt="1000 Years Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td>
        <td><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v298/Decinoge/bg2_img.png" alt="Table Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can also try like it -

```css
table{
       border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td{
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    position:relative;
    display: block;
}
img:hover {
     -webkit-animation: example 1s 1 ease;
    animation: example 1s 1 ease;
    top:100px;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {top:0;}
    100% {top: 100px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0% {top:0;}
    100% {top: 100px;}   
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v298/Decinoge/bg2_img.png" alt="ARDL Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td> 
        <td><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v298/Decinoge/bg2_img.png" alt="1000 Years Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td>
        <td><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v298/Decinoge/bg2_img.png" alt="Table Thumb" width="270" height="203"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope will also helps you.

Comment: There is no need for keyframes, [just use a transition like this example](https://jsbin.com/moyiqe/edit?html,css,output) and use `td:hover img, td img:hover` so that the hover is active when the table cell is hovered and doesn't jump.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you. Is there any way to set this up so that the image can be taller than the TD without stretching the TD to fit the image? That way when it moves down it can expose another portion of the image.

Comment: Sorry but, I'm getting you properly